# Get data in controller ( laravel ) from mongodb model and pass it to view

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I use jeremykenedy/laravel-auth
User is stored in postgres.
Position_info is stored in mongo.
need to get a document from mongo with user_id == $user->getAttribute('id')
In controller (UsersManagementController.php)

```
    ...
public function show(User $user)
{
    $position = Position_info::where('user_id', $user->getAttribute('id'));
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'The Position ID is: '. $position->_id;
    echo '</pre>';
    return view('usersmanagement.show-user', compact('user'))->with('position', $position);;
}
    ...
```

Position_info.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Position_info extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'position_infos';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'position', 'experience', 'additional_info'
    ];
}
```

routes from there
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/routes/web.php

What is displayed on the view

```
error: Property [_id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.
```

Comment: are you directly using eloquent as eloquent does not support no-sql dbs I suppose

Comment: position_info create with Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent

Comment: write more details in your question such as complete tech stack you are using your desired output and your current state

Comment: Don't you just need to do `->get()`?  `Position_info::where('user_id', $user->getAttribute('id'))->get();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```php
$position = Position_info::where('user_id', $user->getAttribute('id'))->get()->toArray();
```

Then to get the _id use this:

```php
echo 'The Position ID is: '. $position[0]['_id'];
```

Comment: I have not fully explained.
User is stored in postgres.
Position_info is stored in mongo. 

need to get a document from mongo with user_id = $ user-> getAttribute ('_ id')

Comment: @ErikMark use this: `$position = Position_info::where('user_id', $user->getAttribute('id'))->get()->toArray();` Then to get _id use this `echo $position[0]['_id'];`